# Drawable ressource file with string Android

Tags: android, xml, mobile

Hi I'm a beginner in kotlin/ android programming I'm trying to add a string and a image to an xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    android:width="234dp"
    android:height="56dp"
    android:viewportWidth="234"
    android:viewportHeight="56"
    >

    <group>

        <clip-path
            android:pathData="M28 0H206C221.464 0 234 12.536 234 28C234 43.464 221.464 56 206 56H28C12.536 56 0 43.464 0 28C0 12.536 12.536 0 28 0Z"
            />

        <path
            android:pathData="M0 0V56H234V0"
            android:fillColor="#34AB8F"
            />
        <!--
        Add string "Click on me"
        -->
        <!--
       Add image: beautifulImage.png
       -->

    </group>

</vector>
```

Do you know the solution, is-it possible?

Comment: please add one example of what do you want. I think it is possible with a constraint layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML you have shared is of vector drawable in which you can't add a string or an image like this and it's not possible, if you want to add a string to this drawable or an image(vector image) you need to have `svg` file of this drawable which you can edit in software like `Adobe illustrator` or `Inkscape`.

After editing it, you can import it into your android studio project using `Resource manager`

Answer (score 0):

Mostly Android developer use JPG or SVG format for images.
JPG is easy to add(with string) in studio.

BUT, In SVG format string is not supported. You have to convert string into shapes. You can do this in Adobe Illustrator by choosing expanding option(in Object Menu) while selecting text.